# close mysql connection after page changes

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have 2 procedure `insertTemp()` and `Search()`.

Here is InsertTemp():

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertTemp`(
    IN keyword TEXT
    )
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempResult;
    CREATE  TEMPORARY TABLE TempResult
    (
    id            INT(11),
    title       TEXT,
    author    TEXT,
    publisher   TEXT,
    );              

    INSERT INTO tempCariOpac
    SELECT * from TempResult;  

    END
```

and Search():

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Search`(
IN limit1 INT, 
IN limit2 INT,
)
BEGIN
SELECT * from catalogs     

      LIMIT limit1,limit2;    
END
```

On my first page I execute `InsertTemp()` and `Search()` and on my 2nd page I run Search() only, because on 1st page I've already run `InsertTemp()` and Create Temporary table. `Search()` was searching data from temporary table but after go to 2nd page my temporary table is not exist. I think it's caused by a closed connection.

Can I make the sql connection keepalive?

In .Net I don't have this problems.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary table is only visible to the connection which created it. There could be 300 temporary tables, all by the same name, and non interrupting or conflicting with each other. In fact, you cannot access temporary tables created by other connections.

So when you query, you get results from the temporary table created by the same connection.

If you close a connection, the temporary table gets dropped. So, moral of the story, create a temporary table then query it, all within the same connection.

HOWEVER, try this method to create persistent connection of mysql from php, which may help you out.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php